# Rotating angular velocities

Tags: transformation, rotations, orientation

I have a quadcopter with yaw, pitch, roll and their respective derivatives `p`, `q` and `r`. Although the orientation is already defined in the world frame, the derivatives are not. This may sound weird, so let me illustrate:

[image]

In (A), the drone is aligned with the world frame axes so that the yaw, pitch, and roll are all $0 °$. In (B), the drone has rotated about the z-axis so that its yaw is now $90 °$. Now imagine the drone starts tilting forward (i.e. pitching) from orientation B.

- In drone frame, this corresponds with pitch movement with some nonzero `p`
- In world frame, this should correspond with roll movement with some nonzero `q` as result

So given the orientation, how do I compute the `p,q,r` in the world frame? **How do I rotate angular velocity?**

Answer (score 0):

I have found the result, you do it in exactly the same way as you rotate positions. So

`[p',q',r'] = [p,q,r] * R(yaw,pitch,roll)`